# How can I debug an npm module compiled with webpack?

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm, webpack

Is there a way to put breakpoints and execute the code step-by-step in the code of an npm module which is compiled with webpack?

The compiled code is not that useful for debugging and when the module is imported locally with `npm link`, only the compiled code is accessed from an application using the module.

How to do this in VSCode (or in any other code editor/ide)?

Answer (score 1):

you can debug that easily in the browser if you add this row to `webpack.config` file:

```
  devtool: "inline-source-map"
```

and then run the scripts in dev mode:

```
--mode development
```

Then, if you set the `debugger` keyword in your npm package and run that in your main project you will see the full code:

[image]

I found another very good article about that topic if you want to learn more
https://blog.jakoblind.no/debug-webpack-app-browser/

Comment: thanks  devtool: "inline-source-map" works for me !!